# Java_home incorrect path in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Any idea why am I getting this error in IntelliJ 2016 terminal

why is it searching in (x86) folder?

[image]

**EDIT**
System Variables contains JAVA_HOME and none is User Variables
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the setting of the environment variable `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: Because you are using java 1.8.0_101 for IntelliJ and that is installed in x86 folder, Can you please check you java path in IntelliJ  module sdk path.

Comment: Error clearly says - JAVA_HOME set to invalid directory. It should be JDK location and not jre path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things has to be checked in order to develop a Java based programs:

**1) Install a JDK when developing Java based applications**

Ensure that you have installed a "Java *Development* Kit", aka `JDK`. The windows explorer that you have shown (most right image), shows that the path points to `JRE` which stands for "Java *Runtime* Environment" kit. If you want to run Java based applications, a `JRE` is sufficient.

*--EDIT (December 2018)--*

As per Oracle announcement to end with public releases of "Java SE" ([road map](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-se-support-roadmap.html))), two links got provided: one leading to a **commercial** license of Oracle JDK and another one released under an **open source** (= "free") license of it. If you are in a work environment, or working on a legacy codebase, please consult your colleagues/manager about which version to take. It depends if there is an Oracle support contract or not. Personal users (hobbyists, students, researchers, ...) can use the free license (unless they have an Oracle Support contract...)

*--end edit--*

If you want to develop a Java based application, you need a `JDK` which can be downloaded at:

1. (free license) [Oracle OpenJDK](https://jdk.java.net/)
2. (with commercial license) [Java SE / Oracle JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

**2) The `JAVA_HOME` path must point to the JDK installation directory**

The path should point to the installation directory of your `JDK`. [image: 1 image description here]

--> if image hosting service is failing to display, here are the steps:

1. Go to the system information (`control panel -> system & security -> system`
2. Click on "Advanced system settings"
3. A new window opens, titled with "System properties". Click on "advanced" tab
4. There, you see "Environment variables" button at the bottom.
5. Ensure that `JAVA_HOME` points to the directory of your java sdk installation (usually `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.<version>`)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, IntelliJ wasn't grabbing the JAVA_HOME environment variable on my Macbook.  I had to close my project and then configure project options to add a pointer to my JDK:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Setting-up-IntelliJ-IDEA

Answer (score 0):

**Error clearly says - JAVA_HOME set to invalid directory.**

JAVA_HOME should be JDK path and not jre location.

Please refer here for more details [JAVA Home Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/)

Example - JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

> To set the JAVA_HOME variable: Locate the Java installation directory
>
> If you didn't change the path during installation, it'll be something
>   like
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
>
> ```
> Do one of the following:
> Windows 7 – Right click My Computer and select Properties > Advanced
> Windows 8 – Go to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings
>
>
> Click the Environment Variables button
> Under System Variables, click New
>
>
> In the Variable Name field, enter either:
>     JAVA_HOME if you installed the JDK (Java Development Kit)
>     or
>     JRE_HOME if you installed the JRE (Java Runtime Environment)
> ```

Refer Here for more details - [Setting Java Home](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html)